# How to display a text with the style of an error in JavaFX?

Tags: css, text, javafx, styles

I'm currently developing a simple text editor using JavaFX and I want to display grammatical errors using a similar style to the one used by Microsoft Word and many other text editors, as shown in the picture.

[Picture of a word with the style I want to reproduce.](http://prntscr.com/9msaml)

I display the text using a javafx.scene.control.TextArea and I'm able to change the text and background colours using:

```
t.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black; -fx-text-fill: white);
```

I've searched for similar CSS parameters to change the style of a word in order to reproduce this style but I've had no luck.

The referred TextArea displays the whole the text and, my concern, for now, is to reproduce the desired style in the whole text. However I did find that it was not possible to change the style of a substring in the text using a TextArea and that a possible solution to that was to use StyleClassedTextArea, from [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX).

Comment: Is t the entire TextArea or is it only holding the incorrect word? Or in other words: did you manage to  only mark the incorrect word with your css so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could underline it with something like this:

```
t.setStyle("-fx-border-insets: 0; -fx-border-width: 2px; -fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-style: hidden hidden solid hidden;");
```

Just underlining is not exactly what you asked for, but while javafx can parse any valid css, it will not output you any style from anything that is not mentioned here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph
You probably already knew that, but in case you didn't, your limitations are bound to the javafx css reference - you can only use the listed statements. Also, if you haven't already,  I highly recommend you have a look at the reference (which has all the possible styles listed), and maybe you'll find a combination that you like.

**Edit:**

I got another idea which is not a super dynamic approach but it should get the job done. You could use `-fx-background-image` with and background image that has the "wavy" underline and the exact height of your font and the required line-height and use `-fx-background-repeat` to repeat the image horizontally.